# Select dinámico con Grails 3.2.10

Tags: jquery, json, grails

Estoy desarrollando tres selects dinámicos con jQuery con el framework de desarrollo web Grails. Los tres selects son:

- Curso
- Titulacion
- Asignatura

Los dos primeros selects ("Curso" y "Titulacion") se muestran perfectamente en sus respectivos desplegables. A continuación mostraré el código:

```js
<script>

    //Seleccion dinamica 'cursoAcademico' -> 'titulacion'
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#cursoAcademico").on('change', function() {
            opcionCursoAcademico = $(this).val()

            alert("El curso academico es: " + opcionCursoAcademico)

            $("#titulacion").empty();
            var URL = "${createLink(controller:"Titulacion", action:"selectCursoAcademico")}"

            $.ajax({
                url: URL,
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    cursoAcademico_id: opcionCursoAcademico
                },
                success: function (data) {

                    $.each(data, function(id,value){
                        $("#titulacion").append('<option value="'+id+'">'+value+'</option>');
                    });
                    //alert("El dato es: " + data)
                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {
                    alert("El error es: " + error);
                },
                complete: function () {
                }
            });

        }); //fin 'cursoAcademico' -> 'titulacion'

        $("#titulacion").on('change', function() {
            opcionTitulacion = $(this).val();

            alert("La opcion de la titulacion es: " + opcionTitulacion)

            $("#asignatura").empty();
            var URL = "${createLink(controller:"Titulacion", action:"selectTitulacion")}"

            $.ajax({
                url: URL,
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    titulacion_id: opcionTitulacion
                },
                success: function (data) {

                    /*$.each(data, function(id,value){
                     $("#asignatura").append('<option value="'+id+'">'+value+'</option>');
                     });*/
                    alert("El dato es: " + data)

                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {
                    alert("El error es: " + error);
                },
                complete: function () {
                }
            });
        });//fin 'titulacion' -> 'asignatura'

    })//fin seleccion dinamica

</script>
```

Como podéis apreciar la linea de código, captura la opción que ha sido seleccionada y realiza la consulta a la BBDD (HQL) de forma satisfactoria.

```
alert("El curso academico es: " + opcionCursoAcademico)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, el **problema** ocurre cuando selecciono una opción del desplegable "Titulación", el cuál muestra lo que yo creo que es el identificador y no el contenido de la opción seleccionada.

```
opcionTitulacion = $(this).val();
alert("La opcion de la titulacion es: " + opcionTitulacion)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando yo pulso en las opciones de dicho desplegable ("Titulación"), ocurre:

- Pulso la opción "Ingeniería Civil" y me muestra un "0" en el alert.
- Pulso la opción "Ingeniería Informática" y me muestra un "1" en el alert.

Posteriormente se realiza una consulta a la BBDD (HQL), pero no se me muestran las opciones en el tercer desplegable("Asignatura"), el cuál intuyo que los valores obtenidos al seleccionar una opción del segundo desplegable ("Titulación") no existen en la BBDD.

¿Cómo podría solucionar este problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He resuelto el problema, estaba obteniendo la "posición" de la opción seleccionada en vez obtener el "contenido" de la opción seleccionada. Se han realizado los siguientes cambios:

1º) Se ha sustituido esta línea de código...

```
opcionCursoAcademico = $(this).val()
```

por la que se muestra a continuación...

```
opcionCursoAcademico = $("#cursoAcademico option:selected").text();
```

2º) Además también se ha sustituido la siguiente linea de código...

```
opcionTitulacion = $(this).val();
```

por la que se muestra a continuación...

```
opcionTitulacion = $("#titulacion option:selected").text();
```